# Openoffice Calc - Changes case of text

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am trying to type

FValue

in a cell. Openoffice changes it to

Fvalue

The cell is set to be a text cell. I have unchecked Recalculate, AutoCalculate and AutoInput under Tools > Cell Contents.

How can I make it quit making this change? I just want to type what I want to type, no autocorrections, thank you very much :/

Comment: The newest 7.4.4.2 seems to be back to this sort of issue. In my situation I want `Word Name` but it keeps forcing all lowercase when I exit the cell because another cell in the column is already `word name` It does not matter what method I use to select or exit the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:
Tools -> AutoCorrect Options... -> tab Options -> uncheck Correct TWo INitial CApitals